# Calculating displacement from velocity equation with scipy.integrate.quad in python

Tags: python

I am a total beginner in python and I am really stuck in this piece of code.

The code is a simulation of a rocket launching
What I want to do is calculate and store the displacement done by the rocket with time.
To be able to plot displacement vs time.

The rocket velocity (u_rocket) depends on t and m(t) (m_rocket)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Dma.png

- u_e and g are a constant
- m(t) is the current mass of the rocket with equation
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFJaZ.png
- m(0) is the initial rocket mass (includes the whole fuel)
- m_b is the rocket mass when there's no more fuel
- t_b is the time at which fuel is finished

I've tried defining u_rocket, but when it's integrated I get -ve values.

How should I define u_rocket so it takes into consideration m_rocket and t?
Should I nest m_rocket function inside u_rocket ?

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
import numpy as np

# Constants
Grav = 9.81
RocketMass = 1000.0 # Kg          # with no fuel
JetArea = 0.1**2*np.pi # m^2    
JetVel = 1500.0 # m/s           # initial jet velocity
RocketMass_ignition = RocketMass + 1500.0  # mass of rocket a ignition 
Burnout_time = 31.83 #s
        
# define the velocity function

def m_rocket(t):
    return RocketMass_ignition*(RocketMass_ignition - RocketMass)*(t/Burnout_time)
    
def u_rocket(t):
    return -JetVel*np.log(m_rocket(t)/RocketMass_ignition) - Grav*t
    
i = quad(u_rocket,0,20)
```

Comment: I'm confused about which direction has positive velocity and which direction has negative.  If you want the rocket's direction of travel to correspond to positive velocity, does the jet velocity have to have the opposite sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems something is wrong with expression for the current mass of the rocket. It should decrease with the time (as rocket consumes fuel), but in your case it increases. I think that's why you get negative values of ve.

Comment: Right. I didn't catch that